# What does Chrome Network Timings really mean and what does affects each timing length?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, google-chrome-devtools

I was looking at chrome dev tools #[resource network timing](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing) to detect requests that must be improved. In the link before there's a definition for each timing but I don't understand what processes are being taken behind the scenes that are affecting the length of the period.

Below are 3 different images and here is my understanding of what's going on, please correct me if I'm wrong.

**Stalled:** Why there are timings where the request get's stalled for 1.17s while others are taking less?

**Request Sent**: it's the time that our request took to reach server

**TTFB**: Time took until the server responds with the first byte of data

**Content Download**: The time until the whole response reaches the client

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Network is an area where things will vary greatly. There are a lot of different numbers that go into play with these and they vary between different locations and even the same location with different types of content.

Here is some more detail on the areas you need more understanding with:

**Stalled:** This depends on what else is going on in the network stack. One thing could not be stalled at all, while other requests could be stalled because 6 connections to the same location are already open. There are more reasons for stalling, but the maximum connection limit is an easy way to explain why it may occur.

The stalled state means, we just can't send the request right now it **needs** to wait for some reason. Generally, this isn't a big deal. If you see it a lot and you are **not** on the HTTP2 protocol, then you should look into minimizing the number of resources being pulled from a given location. If you are on HTTP2, then don't worry too much about this since it deals with numerous requests differently.

Look around and see how many requests are going to a single domain. You can use the filter box to trim down the view. If you have a lot of requests going off to the same domain, then that is most likely hitting the connection limit. *Domain sharding* is one method to handle this with HTTP 1.1, but with HTTP 2 it is an anti-pattern and hurts performance.

If you are not hitting the max connection limit, then the problem is more nuanced and needs a more hands-on debugging approach to figure out what is going on.

**Request sent:** This is not the time to reach the server, that is the Time To First Byte. All request sent means is the request is sent and it took the network stack X time to carry it out.

Nothing you can do to speed this up, it is more for informational and internal debugging purposes.

**Time to First Byte (TTFB):** This is the total time for the sent request to get to the destination, then for the destination to process the request, and finally for the response to traverse the networks back to the client.

A high TTFB reveals one of two issues. The first is a bad network connection between the client and server. So data is slow to reach the server and get back. The second cause is, a slow server processing the request. This is either because the hardware is weak or the application running is slow. Or, both of these problems can exist at once.

To address a high TTFB, first cut out as much network as possible. Ideally, host the application locally on a low-resource virtual machine and see if there is still a big TTFB. If there is, then the application needs to be optimized for response speed. If the TTFB is super-low locally, then the networks between your client and the server are the problem. There are various ways to handle this that I won't get into since it is an area of expertise unto itself. Research network optimization, and even try moving hosts and seeing if your server providers network is the issue.

Remember the entire server-stack comes into play here. So if nginx or apache are configured poorly, or your database is taking a long time to respond, or your cache is having trouble, then these can cause delays. They are also difficult to detect locally, since your local server could vary in configuration from the remote stack.

**Content Download:** This is the total time from the TTFB resolving for the client to get the rest of the content from the server. This should be short unless you are downloading a large file. You should take a look at the size of the file, the conditions of the network, and then judge about how long this should take.

Comment: More details on all timings in here:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476749#c9 and Queueing is simplified here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31373122/89484

Comment: Some years has passed and some new articles were made on this subject. One of them is this: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#timing-explanation

Comment: "_All request sent means is the request is sent and..._" So, what qualifies as a request sent? Unfortunately for me, Chrome Devtool's reference is neither clear on this matter.