# High network TTFB times on local and remote server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, performance, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am addressing slowness in a few http calls for an Angular 1.3, NodeJS, Postgres DB app stack. Remote is hosted on AWS EC2 instances.

[Google's dev tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing) gave me some good understanding of the timings, and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240207/what-does-chrome-network-timings-really-mean-and-what-does-affects-each-timing-l) explains things you can do about it.

My network response for a particular HTTP call shows slowness in TTFB (time-to-first-byte), sometimes as slow as `3s` added in the ttfb timing, indicating either:

> a) A bad network connection between the client and
>   server. So data is slow to reach the server and get back.
>
> b) A slow server processing the request. This is either because the
>   hardware is weak or the application running is slow. Or, both of these
>   problems can exist at once.

What I've tried:

- Comparing local and remote AWS response timings yield similar slowness. So it doesn't appear the networks between my client and my server are the problem
- Running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the queries in question yield fast processing time < 2ms
- We use Redis caching for other parts of the server, but not this particular call

**My question is**: If it doesn't appear there's much difference in speed between remote and local, and the query times are fairly quick, what else could be adding slowness? Is there some middleware or processing on the Node side, or some throttling going on from Angular?

Curiously, what I've also found is the TTFB timing occassionally varies wildly for the same request... with TTFB time < 500ms, and other times TTFB > 3s. Why is this?

Network response:

[image]

EXPLAIN ANALYZE results of the queries in question:

```
 Planning time: 0.915 ms
 Execution time: 1.687 ms
(30 rows)
```

---

Versions:

**Postgres**: 9.6.1

```
select version();

 PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81), 64-bit
```

**Node**: 7.4.0

**Knex**: 0.12.6

**Angular**: 1.3

Comment: Which database library are you using and which version?

Comment: @vitaly-t added above

Comment: I asked about the database library, not about the version of the server.

Comment: @vitaly-t sorry how can I check this?

Comment: You don't know which library you are using to access PostgreSQL from Node.js? What module executes your SQL queries from Node.js?

Comment: @vitaly-t ahh sorry `knex` 0.12.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134326/discussion-between-growler-and-vitaly-t).

Answer (score 1):

> Comparing local and remote AWS response timings yield similar slowness.

This points to the most likely cause of the problem - inefficient use of database connections.

The inconsistent TTFB comes from the fact that sometimes your request arrives while all available connections are consumed and not released on time. The default `pg` driver in this case causes a wait period till a connection becomes available in the pool.

To solve this, you need to look into how you use the connections:

- the size of the pool
- the way connections are managed in all requests

Comment: Vitaly, how can I check connections to this detail? How can I check the size of the pool and the way connections are managed?

Comment: @Growler as far as I know, knex implements its own connection pool, one that's separate from the `node-postgres` driver's default pool. I'm not familiar with knex pool management, unfortunately, you need to research this yourself.