# Monitor active DB connections at a point in time

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, connection-pooling, knex.js

In reference to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926212/high-network-ttfb-times-on-local-and-remote-server?noredirect=1#comment71033504_41926212), I'm experiencing slowness with Time-to-first-byte in my NodeJS app, using Knex as the database library.

Versions:

- **Postgres**: 9.6.1
- **Node**: 7.4.0
- **Knex**: 0.12.6
- **Angular**: 1.3

It was suggested that:

> To solve this, you need to look into how you use the connections:
>
> - the size of the pool
> - the way connections are managed in all requests

When I run an http request, how can I view the active connections and how knex is managing the pool? How can I be sure my connections are being used optimally?

Pool knex config in Node:

```
pool: {
  min: 2,
  max: 8,
}
```

Comment: Optimal pool usage is dictated by the application requirements. I don't know if knex can offer you that kind of flexibility. It abstracts a lot, often more than one needs to fully control your app for optimization.

Comment: You need a decent instrumentation layer to help monitor the individual transactions and timing across various platform components you are using. I don't know many free ones that are worth trying but I happen to use NewRelic. They probably have a free dev version - adding it is a simple `require` statement at the top of your Node app. You should be able to see - with little to no effort - a per transaction breakdown of time and resources across Postgres, Node etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Run your app with `DEBUG=knex:*` environment variable and you will see quite detailed info what is happening + timings inside `knex` when you launch your request.

Should give you enough information to see where the time is passing.

If you like to request stats directly from `generic-pool` like this:

```
knex = require('knex')({client: 'pg', connection: 'postgres:///knex_test'})
poolStats = {
  connectionsAvailable: knex.client.pool.availableObjectsCount(),
  connectionsUsed: knex.client.pool.inUseObjectsCount(),
  clientsWaitingForConnection: knex.client.pool.waitingClientsCount(),
};

{ connectionsAvailable: 2,
  connectionsUsed: 0,
  clientsWaitingForConnection: 0 }
```