# Is there any trick to speedup the load time of a js chunk file generated via create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

I have a small react app built with cra that run pretty well in development. After `yarn run build`, 3 js files are generated and one of them has 1,79MB size. Once uploaded to the server, this little file take over 40s-1min to load, I don't understand why. The size is pretty light, right ? If anyone know how I Can figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: You should profile your page with the browser dev tools to get more insight on what's actually slow, it could be the server, download, parsing or execution (or all of them). Then you can solve each problem individually. Maybe start with checking the [netowork timings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240207/what-does-chrome-network-timings-really-mean-and-what-does-affects-each-timing-l) and attach them to the question.

Comment: Over 90% is the "Content Download" time.