# Where is this "stalled" time coming from?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, networking, proxy, timing

This is a screenshot of Chrome's network timing and I'm trying to figure out the "stalled" time of ~250ms. [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#view-network-timing-details-for-a-specific-resource) say the stalled status is for time spent either waiting for a socket (possibly due to max 6 rule) or time spent negotiating a proxy. However, in my case, this is the only active request (so it's not a max 6 issue), and there is no other network activity on the computer or even the network. I'm also not using any form of proxy or VPN.

I eventually figured out that this "stalled" time disappears if I change from https to plain http, so at first, I figured this was SSL setup time. But if that were the case, why isn't it showing up in the "SSL" section of the timing?

What's causing this "stalled" time taking 30% of the load time?

[image: screenshot-west-coast-https]

---

## Edit

I had my buddy on the opposite coast hit the same page and it's worse for him, which *suggests* that it could be server-proximity related?

#### HTTPS

[image: screenshot-east-coast-https]

#### HTTP

[image: screenshot-east-coast-http]

Comment: Hello @KOGI . When it comes to Chrome I regard it as a beautiful woman with a lot of mystery. First, have you double-checked that the connections limit does  not apply? Did you check `chrome://networking`? You can also try to monitor Chrome using Wireshark. Or give a try to an HTTP/2 server, the one that I maintain is kind of easy to setup, plus it won't make a secret of the huge number of connections that Chrome makes on his own.

Comment: @dsign It's not a max connections issue since it's just the main document request and there is no other chrome activity at the time. I don't get anything at all for `chrome://networking`, however, I did find `chrome://net-internals`, but I'm not sure what to look at.

Comment: Look to the "sockets" in chrome://net-internals, and there in the table transport_socket_pool to the sum of `active` plus `idle` for your domain. Another thing that comes to my mind if that your Chrome somehow has a limited number of sockets available. From what you write I doubt you are hitting any limits. Yet another thing to research is if you are using Windows with an SSL-intercepting anti-virus (I have seen such). The easiest way to confirm that is by clicking the green padlock icon and seeing if the certificate looks suspicious.

Comment: @dsign, well, the stalled time disappears if I change to plain HTTP, so I think that alone suggests there is no socket availability/limit issue, right? The windows anti-virus is a good thought, though. I've got mine turned off, but it's Windows10, so who knows what other shenanigans might be going on. Also, as far as I can tell, the certificate looks just fine. It's hitting my own webserver, so it's my own cert, too, so I wouldn't expect any issues with it.

Comment: Ok, I had a similar issue a few months ago, I was certainly not using Windows and was using my own server so I don't think is related, but I got a good an answer that may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104147/what-the-emptiness-mean-in-devtools-timings

Comment: @dsign, thank you. Definitely seems related, but in this case, not applicable, it doesn't seem.

Comment: This seems related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476749 You could also sniff with wireshark to see if anything else is going on (DNS requests maybe)?